# Slot load drive won't release disc

Tags: imac, optical-drive

My 2008 iMac's Superdrive (DVR-K06PB) is not releasing discs.  I've opened the drive itself and found the spring loaded lugs on the spindle don't seem to be allowing the disc to release - the mechanism pulls the spindle down, bending the disc slightly, then reloads the disc because it can't release it.  Turning the disc upside down yields proper eject operation (?!).  I've tried various different CDs and DVDs, all seem to have the same problem, some less than others.
I'm wondering if the lugs are protruding just a little too much and will need a bit of a file down to help the release, or even a bit of lube.  Thought I'd come here and get some advice before I did anything.  The drive works just fine in every way except ejection.

Comment: It is telling that the disc is ejected when inserted ‘upside down’, as the only difference is that the data surface is not detected by the drive and is thus the Mac can’t read it and it ejects. Filing down the lugs or putting some lube may fix, but it would introduce instability to the rotation of the spindle. Finding a replacement drive might be your only solution. The first thing I’d try is a [CD lens cleaner disc](https://www.amazon.com/Maxell-CD-340-190048-CD-ROM-Cleaner/dp/B000001OM5) to see if it is just a misreading of the disc somehow.

Comment: It's definitely not a misreading of the disc.  The drive is fully operational except it will not physically eject the disc.  I have the drive cover off and I'm watching the mechanisms work.  It's physically struggling to pull the disc off the spindle.  I can't even pull it off without pushing the lugs in to release it.  Upside down, it comes off as (I believe) it should.

Comment: Perhaps there’s a malfunctioning release mechanism that is software controlled when the drive senses it is reading (or has read) data? Have you tried the multitudinous ways to eject a disc. I found a comprehensive list [here](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/05/01/the-ultimate-guide-to-ejecting-a-stuck-disc-from-mac-superdrive/).